# Как передать кейс в условие

Tags: c++

Есть свич, в котором 7 кейсов, хочу каждый кейс передать в условия функции turnOrders.

```
switch(choose){
    case 1 : cout << "Маргарита"; break;
    case 2 : cout << "Пепперони"; break;
    case 3 : cout << "Грибная"; break;
    case 4 : cout << "Четыре сыра"; break;
    case 5 : cout << "Кальцоне"; break;
    case 6 : cout << "Неаполитанская"; break;
    case 7 : cout << "Римская"; break;
    default : cout << "Нет такого варианта";
}



void turnOrders(vector<string>turn, Turn &choose){ //Очередь заказов 
    if(choose == 1){ // тут непонятно что написать 
        turn.push_back("Маргарита");
    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите... Зачем там что-то писать? Вернее, что там должно быть сделано? А вообще, я бы оформил все это с использованием массива и не мучился с этими соп... пардон, макаронами из if'ов и case'ов... P.S. и зачем передавать `choose` как ссылку, а `turn` наоборот, по значению (т.е. терять все изменения по выходе из функции)?

Comment: массив наименований : `array[]={"Маргарита",..,"Римская"}` => `turn.push_back(array[choose]);`